# Can ajax converted to php curl?

Tags: php

So i want to convert ajax into PHP CURL, can it happen? how do I do it?  below is the ajax program can it converted to PHP code? i really appreciated if someone can help me

thank you

````
    $('input[name="target"],input[name="target2"],select[name="target2"]').change(function(){
        var target = $("#target").val();
        var target2 = $("#target2").val();
        var category_code ='ADD';
                    var paramTarget2 = '';
            if($('#target2').length) {
                paramTarget2 = '&target2='+target2;
            }

            var postdata='category=' + category_code+'&target='+target+paramTarget2;

            if(target != '') {
                if($('#target2').length && target2 != '') {
                    validasi(postdata);
                } else if ($('#target2').length == 0) {
                    validasi(postdata);
                }
            }
            });      
    function validasi(postdata){
                $.ajax({
            url: 'https://www.yoursite.com/check.php',
            data: postdata,
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'JSON',
            beforeSend: function() {
                Swal.fire({title:"Please Wit",showConfirmButton:false,allowOutsideClick:false});
            },
            success: function(data) {
                if(data.result ==false){     
                    Swal.fire('Ups...'," Not Found",'error');
                }else{
                    Swal.fire('Sukses !',"User Found",'success');
                    document.getElementById("displayname").value = decodeURI(data.data.name);
                }
            }
        });
            }; ```
````

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

```
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "myserverthing.php",
            data: {time: timestamp,
                   prog: progName,
                   qual: qualifier,
                   level: lvl, 
                   msg: message 
            }
        });
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a basic way for setting up a post request via curl

```
   <?php
    

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://www.yoursite.com/check.php");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
        "postv1=value1&postv2=value2&postv3=value3");

    //Setting the operation would look like this:
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 
              http_build_query(array('postv1' => 'value1')));

    // Receive response ...
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    $server_output = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close ($ch);

    // Do some further processing 
    if ($server_output == "OK") { doSomething() } else { handleThis() }
    ?>
```

So step 1). Initialize CURL session

```
    $ch = curl_init();
```

step 2). Provide options for the CURL session

```
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.yoursite.com/check.php");
```

CURLOPT_URL -> the URL u want to fetch
CURLOPT_HEADER -> including header or not including header
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER -> if it is set to true, data is returned as string instead of outputted.

```
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER, true); //if you want headers
```

step 3). Execute the CURL session

```
    $output=curl_exec($ch);
```

step 4). Close the session

```
    curl_close($ch);
```